# Apex example Code to copy Account field values

Tags: scheduled-apex

I am new to SalesForce. My goal is to create a scheduled Apex function that runs once all 24hours that just copies Account.Field("field1").Value to Account.Field("field2").Value. Is there a good example code page or tutorial to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this realtime with a trigger? Do you want to do this for every account?

Comment: yes, it should only be all 24 hours using the "schedule apex" function. And yes it should be for every account. Background: I have a data_today field and a data_daybefore field. I just want to save a copy of todays data to a separate field so I can compare my data with that on the day before

Comment: @user670186 For learning the apex workbook is better if you are new to force.com platform

Comment: An alternative to this could be to turn on [Field History Tracking](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/tracking_field_history.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement for you is good exercise as a fresher.

Please use the trailhead module to explore scheduled job and batch apex

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex

Comment: Thanks you! The examples are very generic though, I will try

Comment: Documentation is not available anymore

Comment: @paranza Thanks for pointing out i just substituted with trailhead modules .